# indexOf doesn't work with my list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm trying to get the index of a span element which I have put in a list. So I create the list with all the elements, but when I'm trying to get the index of an element, by clicking on one of the elements, I've got the error "indexOf is not a function". What can I do to solve this problem and have the expected output ?

```js
var mdr;
window.onload = function() {
  mdr = document.getElementsByClassName("lol");
  for (let i = 0; i < mdr.length; i++) {
    mdr[i].addEventListener("click", haha);
  };
};

function haha() {
  console.log(mdr.indexOf(this));
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lol">1</div>
<div class="lol">2</div>
<div class="lol">3</div>
<div class="lol">4</div>
<div class="lol">5</div>
```

Comment: `mdr` is not an array. use `Arrayf.from(mdr).indexOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `getElementsByClassName()` method of Document interface returns an ***array-like*** object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

As the result returned by `getElementsByClassName()` is not an array `indexOf()` is not available on the result set.

Try with [`Spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
[...mdr].indexOf(this)
```

**OR:** With  [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

> The `Array.from()` method creates a new, shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

```
Array.from(mdr).indexOf(this)
```

```js
var mdr;
window.onload = function() {
   mdr = document.getElementsByClassName("lol");
   for (let i = 0; i < mdr.length; i++) {
       mdr[i].addEventListener("click", haha);
   };
};

function haha() {
   console.log(Array.from(mdr).indexOf(this));
};
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lol">1</div>
<div class="lol">2</div>
<div class="lol">3</div>
<div class="lol">4</div>
<div class="lol">5</div>
```